# Why is my batch file not working?

Tags: .net, batch-file, registry

Something is failing because of the spacing in the key name, but using quotes is not helping and setting it to a variable did not help?

Thanks

```
@echo off
set key="hklm\software\microsoft\net framework setup\ndp"
 for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('reg query %key% ^| Find /i "ndp\"') do (
     for /f "tokens=2,* delims= " %%b in ('reg query %%a /v Install') do (
         echo %%c,%%~na
     )
 )
```

Comment: What do you want to do with this batch?

Comment: What are you intending to do here? Cuold you please specify it a bit better?

Answer (score 1):

Your outer loop has quotes around the key, but your inner loop reg query is missing quotes around the key. The following works for me. I prefer to keep quotes out of my variable values, and then explicitly provide them where needed. So I modified the outer loop a bit as well.

```
@echo off
set "key=hklm\software\microsoft\net framework setup\ndp"
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('reg query "%key%" ^| find /i "ndp\"') do (
  for /f "tokens=2,* delims= " %%b in ('reg query "%%a" /v Install') do (
    echo %%c,%%~na
  )
)
```